# Error loading document - Firestore database (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to view the users in my database, I get this error:

[image]

But, when I try to register some users from my android application, it runs!

---

There're too much errors... Loot at this...

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SWLz.png)

[image]

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: What are the numbers of users present in that collection ?

Comment: Check the JavaScript console of your browser for errors. If there's nothing there, open an incognito window, disable all browser extensions and try loading the console there. If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for help guys :D